# What does a pointer instead a name in a struct of a struct mean?

Tags: c, struct

What does *rooms[10] mean in this code? isn't it usually struct Room ? What does it mean in this case?

```
struct Room
{
     float width;
     float length;
     float height;
     char *name;
};

struct House
{
     char* address;
     struct Room *rooms[10];
};
```

Comment: It means that the array contains pointers to the structs, not the structs themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

```
struct House
{
     char* address;
     struct Room rooms[10];
};
```

you have 10 **full** instances of a `Room`. That is your `House` structure size is 10 times the size of the `Room` structure plus some extra (for the `address`). Also, all 10 of these are in nearby locations in memory, causing higher fragmentation.

On the other hand, in

```
struct House
{
     char* address;
     struct Room *rooms[10];
};
```

you only have to store pointers to 10 rooms (which need to be allocated on the heap). In the first case when you call a function with `House` as parameter your stack is blown up because it needs a huge structure to be stored there while on the second case a much smaller structure is copied, resulting in faster function calls.